# QT QWebView change mouse position

Tags: qt

Im making a co-browsing app for learning purposes, using a QWebView to simulate the other users screen.

The problem Im currently having is that I receive mouse movements from the server very fast and that causes the mouse to seem "sluggish".

My current method is to load `jQuery` into the webview and then insert a div which will act as the other users mouse. I then move that div according to the coordinates i receive - but this is really laggy.

Here is my current code to do just that:

```
    // Create the div when the view loads.
    ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("$(document).ready(function() {$('html').append(\'<div id=\"clientCursor\" style=\"background-image:url(https://ssl.url.com/assets/cursor.png); position: absolute; z-index: 1; height: 22px; width: 22px; top: 1px\"></div>\'); });");

    // And the moving part:
    void browsing::recieveMouseMovement(QString x, QString y) {
        ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("$(\'#clientCursor\').css({\'left\': " + x + ", \'top\': " + y + "});");
    }
```

I also tried :

`ui->webView->cursor().setPos(x, y);`

But that seems to move my own desktop mouse..

Any ideas if there is a more optimal way of simulating a moving mouse?

Comment: Idea to possibly reduce jquery method lag: poll mouse position With timer from JavaScript at last possible moment before setting position of div. Experiment to find a good poll interval, but 50msec might be a good start.